# How to find the unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I have a bunch of unit tests in my visual studio project and code coverage coloring shows the covered lines of code in blue. Is it possible to jump to the unit test(s) that covers that line of code?

Comment: Put a break point on the line of code, run the unit tests, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I was hoping that since Visual Studio can determine the code is covered by a test and color it blue it could also list all those unit tests similar to the Find All References function.
The break point method does work fine tho so that'll do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Several unit tests may cover the same line, so it's not a 1-1 relationship.

Your best bet is to stick a breakpoint on the line and run the tests and look at the call stack when the break point is hit.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to change that line of code, maybe comment it out, and see which tests fail as a result. May well be quicker than having to manually check each time the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Yeah, nice idea. Perhaps put an Assert.Fail on the line before, with a specific message and see which tests fail with that message.

Comment: Yeah, that would work for tests that test the method. My way would try to find those that rely on the line of the method. Nice idea though.